# How to make C++ template type to default to previous template type

Tags: c++, templates, default-template-argument

Is there any way, to default second template type to the type of the first template argument type, to remove the need of specifying the template types when not needed?

So, I have a method, that pops values from byte array:

```
    template<class TYPE1, class TYPE2>
    bool pop_value_from_array(TYPE2 &value)
    {
        if(get_array_size() >= sizeof(TYPE1))
        {
            value = static_cast<TYPE2>(*reinterpret_cast<const TYPE1*>(get_array_pointer()));
            remove_bytes_from_array(sizeof(TYPE1));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And then I can do

```
    uint32_t size;
    if (!pop_value_from_array<uint16_t>(size))
    {
        // Error handling
    }
    size *= 2;
    uint16_t var2;
    if (!pop_value_from_array<uint16_t>(var2))
    {
        // Error handling
    }
```

If I declare another function:

```
    template<class TYPE>
    bool pop_value_from_array(TYPE &value)
    {
        if(get_array_size() >= sizeof(TYPE))
        {
            value = *reinterpret_cast<const TYPE*>(get_array_pointer());
            remove_bytes_from_array(sizeof(TYPE));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I can get rid of the template specification when not needed:

```
    uint32_t size;
    // Poping uint16_t from array, and storing to the uint32_t type, so there is no overflow in multiplication
    if (!pop_value_from_array<uint16_t>(size))
    {
        // Error handling
    }
    size *= 2;
    uint16_t var2;
    if (!pop_value_from_array(var2))
    {
        // Error handling
    }
```

So, I want to get rid of the second declaration of the same function

Comment: Are these member functions of a class? including `get_array_pointer` / `get_array_size`? It really looks like `TYPE1` should be a known to the class, and then `pop_value_from_array` would only have one template parameter. Otherwise your example has undefined behaviour

Comment: So basically this function can be explained as: if there is enough bytes in array, interpret bytes from array as TYPE1, and static cast it to a TYPE2, and then shift the array pointer

Comment: If the array is not an array of `TYPE1`, then that has undefined behaviour. If it is, why have you type-erased `TYPE1`? You need to `memcpy` into an actual `TYPE1` object to interpret those bytes as a `TYPE1`

Comment: Array is just array of bytes

Comment: Yes, so there isn't a `TYPE1` for you to dereference

Comment: @Caleth No, the TYPE1 is used to interpret the array of bytes (int16 for example), and static casted to int32 for example

Comment: That's what I'm saying. It is undefined behaviour to `reinterpret_cast<const TYPE*>` your bytes

Comment: Why is that undefined behavior?

Comment: Sorry, dereferencing that pointer is undefined behaviour, because `reinterpret_cast` is very specific as to what types you can convert between. You can't magic a `TYPE1` out of bytes, unless `TYPE1` is either `char`, `unsigned char` or `std::byte`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might default `TYPE1` to some special type (I use `void` here), and then check for that type:

```
template<class TYPE1 = void, class TYPE2>
bool pop_value_from_array(TYPE2 &value)
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<void, TYPE1>, TYPE2, TYPE1>;
    // Now use type.
    if(get_array_size() >= sizeof(type))
    {
        value = static_cast<TYPE2>(*reinterpret_cast<const type*>(get_array_pointer()));
        remove_bytes_from_array(sizeof(type));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you have a non-defaulted type parameter follow a defaulted one?

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me, at least for the c++17 version

Comment: [TIL](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d98fa5a1d614aa8)

Comment: @Caleth it works because `TYPE2` is deduced.

Answer (score 0):

Templates parameters can be defaulted:

```
    template<class TYPE1, class TYPE2=TYPE1>
    bool pop_value_from_array(TYPE2 &value)
// ...
```

Now this template can be invoked with just one parameter, and the second one gets defaulted in the expected manner.

There are some restrictions on template parameter defaulting. Your C++ textbook should have the complete details.

Comment: Yeah, but I already can use it with 1 parameter, I want to use it without of parameters at all, when the types are match, and not declaring a second function

Comment: `TYPE2` is deduced, so the default is mostly useless.

Comment: OP wants to default `TYPE1` (as illegal `TYPE1 = TYPE2`).